# socket id is not showing on html client side

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

i am trying to get the socket id on the client side but for some reason it's not showing. Here is my code

client side

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Ringneck</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.indigo-pink.min.css">
    <script src="https://www.WebRTC-Experiment.com/RecordRTC.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/4.4.1/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io-stream/0.9.1/socket.io-stream.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div style="margin: 20px">
        <h1 style="font-size: 18px;">Example 7: Media Translation Streaming</h1>
        <div>
            <button id="start-recording" disabled>Start Streaming</button>
            <button id="stop-recording" disabled>Stop Streaming</button>
        </div>
        <h2 style="font-size: 16px; margin-bottom: 10px;">data.textTranslationResult.translation</h2>
        <p>Record your voice in English, and see the German translation.</p>
        <p>Keep recording for at least 4 seconds.</p>
        <textarea id="results" style="width: 800px; height: 300px;"></textarea>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">

 const startRecording = document.getElementById('start-recording');
    const stopRecording = document.getElementById('stop-recording');
    let recordAudio;

    const socketio = io();
    

    console.log("JS file loaded"). // sanity check to make sure file is read


    const socket = socketio.on('connect', function(msg) {
        console.log("JS file loaded")

        console.log("socket id: ",socket.id);
     });
```

and my server side code

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const path = require('path');

const app = express();
const http = require('http').Server(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(http);
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;


app.use(cors());
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/public/index.html'));
});


function onConnection(socket){
    console.log(`Client connected [id=${socket.id}]`);
    var returndata = {
        "test":"yes"
    }
    socket.emit('server_setup', `Server connected [id=${socket.id}]`);
}
  

io.on('connection', onConnection);


http.listen(port, () => console.log('listening on port ' + port));
```

my server console log is

> Client is connected [id=_RMXhb8Vz9XgSqhGAAGa]

but I could not get any response on the client side. what am i missing and how can i fix this and get the socket id ?

Comment: Why are you trying to create a new server inside of `app.use()`.  This is not correct.  Similarly, there should NOT be `app.get()` inside of `app.use()`.  That is just not how things work with Express or socket.io on the server.   There should be ONE express http server and ONE socket.io instance attached to that Express server created at server startup time.  All http clients and socket.io clients connect to your one server.

Comment: Also, this `const socket = socketio.on('connect', function(msg) { ...});` is very odd because your `socketio` and `socket` variable are exactly the same thing.

Comment: @jfriend00 I have updated the question with my current server code

Answer (score 0):

When I run your code, I found that there was a client-side Javascript parsing error on this line:

```
console.log("JS file loaded").
```

because of the period.  When I replace that period with a semi-colon like this:

```
console.log("JS file loaded");
```

I get this output on the server:

```
Client connected [id=eoxspnNtoTg-2Kj3AAAB]
```

and this output in the debug console of the browser:

```
JS file loaded
socket id:  eoxspnNtoTg-2Kj3AAAB
```

If you're not already doing so, you should be looking in the browser console for errors.